# Postgres serializable snapshot isolation for jsonb

Tags: postgresql, locking, json, concurrency

I'm trying to acquire a serializable lock on a `JSONB` column, but it looks like by default `JSONB` supports only row level lock on transactions.

Basically I want to store JSON like:

```json
{a:"v1", b:"v2"}
```

Here I want to acquire lock on my json, so that when two users edit `a`/`b` concurrently for me database shouldn't block transactions. However, if both user edit the same key concurrently, I want to stop them.

My application needs properties that need to be stored and updated that's the reason I went ahead for `JSONB`. Not sure are there any way to achieve serializable lock on `JSONB`.

The keys will be fixed. They can edit more than one key. No one can delete the JSON keys according to my design, only update them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with `JSONB`.  To get this level of separation, you would have to have a parent and child table, where the child table would be something like:

```
(parent_id whatever, key text, value text, primary key (parent_id, key))
```

If your JSON can be nested and not just a flat key-value store, then it is ambiguous at what level you want the locking to occur.  If it always occurs at the first level, then this would still work but the `value` column would be of type `JSONB`.

If the locking occurs deeper, then that would really be a mess.  What if someone wants to change a value 4 levels down, and someone else wants to remove the entire sub-tree from the 2nd level?

EAV is the design which fits your desired concurrency/locking model. Obviously there are other considerations than that, but I wouldn't know what those are.  You could always use a single row, block until the other guy commits, then "manually" re-check that the value you want to update wasn't changed by the other guy.

Answer (score 1):

I would never do something like this but you can certainly stop a single user from editing two keys.

```
CREATE TABLE foo(frekinJSON)
  AS VALUES ('{"a":1, "b":2}'::jsonb);

CREATE FUNCTION halt()
RETURNS trigger
AS $$
  BEGIN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'NOAP!';
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER halt_in_the_name_of_evan
AFTER UPDATE OF frekinJSON ON foo
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (
      (OLD.frekinJSON->'a' IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.frekinJSON->'a')
      AND (OLD.frekinJSON->'b' IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.frekinJSON->'b')
    )
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE halt();

UPDATE foo SET frekinjson = '{"a":10}';           -- fails (changing a, unsetting b)
UPDATE foo SET frekinjson = '{"a":10, "b":2}';    -- works (changing a)
UPDATE foo SET frekinjson = '{"b":10}';           -- fails (changing b, unsetting a)
UPDATE foo SET frekinjson = '{"a":10,"b":42}';    -- works (changing a)
UPDATE foo SET frekinjson = '{"a":1, "b":2}';     -- fails (both)
UPDATE foo SET frekinjson = '{"a":1, "b":42}';    -- works (changing a)
UPDATE foo SET frekinjson = '{"a":1, "b":2}';     -- works (changing b)
```

Having two users edit the keys concurrently would be a function of the app. And it wouldn't change in a different schema.

```
BEGIN;
  User one's statement;
  User two's statement;
  (logic to commit or rollback)
END;
```